# Why UITableView is not dequeuing reusable cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding subviews with `UITableViewCell` default type. In this, assume that, I've only 2 rows. At first, when it comes to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I'll generate a dynamic identifier for each cell based on `indexPath.row`. So it goes well and create a new cell inside `if(cell == nil)` condition. I'm adding subviews inside this condition only.

Next, out side that condition, I'm simply updating content of subview by fetching them out of the cell's `contentView`. This works great.

Problem is here : I'm expanding my cell (on which user tapped). When I do this, it'll go into `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and I'm able to see the same identifier generated before. However, its going inside `if(cell == nil)` condition.

For a note, I'm checking for that condition like this,

`if(!cell)` and not `if(cell == nil)`.

Can you guess what is the issue? However in my deep investigation, I found that, it'll only goes inside `if(cell == nil)` once I expand particular row and not next time for the same row.

**Here's the sample :**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //number of count
    return [array count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //dynamic height will be provided based on content.
    return [self heightForRow:indexPath];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cellIdentifier_%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [self setupCell:cell forRow:[indexPath row] inTable:tableView];
    }
    [self updateCell:cell forRow:[indexPath row] inTable:tableView];
    return cell;
}

- (void) setupCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRow:(NSInteger)row inTable:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //setting up view here
}

- (void) updateCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRow:(NSInteger)row inTable:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //updating view here
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.expandedIndexPath = ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) ? nil : indexPath;

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.expandedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

Hope my issue is clear to you. Please comment if you don't get something or found anything missing here (and I'll update it here) or answer if you know what's the solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is very strange way of using the identifier... Basically you are not reusing anything at all. Why? That seems very very wrong.

Comment: If you want to keep all the cells loaded, you could simply use a NSMutableDictionary with your cellIdentifier as a key to store/retrieve these cells. But that has nothing to do with reusing cells.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a reusable cell available?  (And which version of `cellForRow...` are you calling?  The one in UITableView, or the one in UITableViewDataSource?)

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, the one is `UITableViewDataSource`. Here it is, `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: @luk2302, yes, you're right, actually, I'm not reusing it, however, I want to keep my each cell unique – so that I'm using dynamic identifiers for each cell.

Comment: @rokjarc, yes, I was thinking off to keep those cells inside a dictionary, but for now, I don't need it, as I mentioned in my question that, for now, I've only two unique cells.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya, yes, I'm aware of this, but this is certainly unnecessary, so if, I want to do in that way, I may simply keep `static` before creating identifier.

Comment: You should be using the version from UITableView, to access the existing cell.  And you should either modify the existing cell or call reload to change the cell's layout.

Comment: (And if you only have two cells you have no need for a TableView.)

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks ! but I guess, you're not getting my problem. I'm able to have proper layout of my cell and its content. The only issue I'm concern about is that its setting up my (those two) cells twice. However, this should happen for once. **Update:** No I'll have more cells in future. That's why I'm using `UITableView`.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a reusable cell available?

Comment: @HotLicks, because I'm using dynamic identifiers, once they get allocated, they don't supposed to go for reallocate.

Comment: in that case you might want to create this two cells as ivars or properties and use a simple switch/case in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: @hagile attach image here how it looks that will help you to get answer quickly

Comment: @rokjarc, as I commented for HotLicks, I'll have more cells in future. I'm only looking for a stable solution.

Comment: @cyberlobe, I've added everything in my question, however this doesn't require any "requirement image". Sorry, I'm not able to add screenshot.